# Embedding a text editor within another Eclipse editor

Tags: eclipse, swt, eclipse-plugin

Is it possible to embed a text editor (with syntax coloring and content assist) within my own custom Eclipse editor? I am under the impression that a text editor (with features like syntax coloring) needs to extend `IEditorPart` or one of its subclasses, but am I correct in thinking that an `IEditorPart` subclass can't be embedded because it's not part of Eclipse SWT? And if that's true, is there another way to get that functionality?

To expand on this "custom Eclipse editor": I'm referring to an editor with multiple tabs, and in one of the tabs I want to embed a text editor with syntax coloring, and possibly content assist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right, you cannot embed `IEditorPart`, instead you could inherit your editor from a concrete `IEditorPart` implementor and override custom aspects thereof.

Comment: Could you expand on that? I can't embed something like `org.eclipse.ui.editors.text.TextEditor` because it doesn't extend `Composite`.

Comment: I'm not talking about embedding, I'm talking about extending some existing editor and overriding available public and protected methods (aka Decoration) to achieve the needed effect. If your "editor" is going to be much more than just a text editor with Eclipse-provided bells and whistles (syntax highlighting, breakpoints, etc.) then this approach will not work for you.

Comment: I edited the question with more info on this "custom editor" I'm referring to.

Comment: Now the things are much more clear. Presuming you have access to the Eclipse sources, I'd check out how the plugin.xml editor is implemented (a number of tabs at the bottom: Overview, Dependencies,..., plugin.xml,...) of which "plugin.xml" seems to be implemented using an XML editor or something of the kind.

Comment: I looked into `MultiPageEditorPart` and it seems I can use that class, or at least mimic its functionality to achieve what I need. Thanks for your help... if you enhance your answer I'll go ahead and accept it.

Comment: I guess I can only give you pointers to some tutorials/discussions, like [this](http://www.eclipsepluginsite.com/editors.html) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8817440/actions-within-a-nested-editor-inside-a-multipageeditorpart-page).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7296/discussion-between-seand-and-alexander-pavlov)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, using a MultiPageEditorPart, where every page is either an IEditorPart or an SWT control.  Keep in mind that the text editor you're embedding has to have been written to still function correctly in that situation.

Answer (score 0):

You can add your editor to MultiPageEditPArt.

```
  final IEditorPart = new YourEditor();
  int editorIndex = addPage(formJSEditor, editorInput);
  setPageText(editorIndex, "Your Editor");
```